# I cannot connect to localhost using my droplet. I can connect to Typesense docker container when I connect through other machines, but not locally

Tags: linux, docker, dart, digital-ocean, typesense

I have a digital a digital ocean droplet ubuntu with docker installed. I installed Typesense container which is running healthy.

if I write curl http://127.0.0.1:8108/health or curl http://localhost:8108/health or curl http://171.122.255.261:8108/health in the command line of my droplet I get

{"ok":true}

171.122.255.261 is the public address of my droplet (fake ip)

So Typesense container is mapped on 8108:8108.

When I try to connect to Typesense via my Dart code I do it like:

```
class MyTypesense with UsersTypesenseQueries {
  @override
  late final Client client;

  MyTypesense() {
    final config = Configuration(
      'xyz',
      nodes: {
        Node.withUri(
          Uri(
            scheme: 'http',
            host: '171.122.255.261',
            port: 8108,
          ),
        ),
      },
      numRetries: 3, // A total of 4 tries (1 original try + 3 retries)
      connectionTimeout: const Duration(seconds: 15),
    );
    client = Client(config);
  }
}
```

This works when I connect to my droplet's typesense via other machines.

But then, if I try to run dart code inside my droplet and connect to typsense like this (it doesnt work):

class TypesenseDatabase {
late final Client client;

```
  TypesenseDatabase() {
    final config = Configuration(
      'xyz',
      nodes: {
        Node.withUri(
          Uri(
            scheme: 'http',
            host: '127.0.0.1',
            port: 8108,
          ),
        ),
      },
      numRetries: 3, // A total of 4 tries (1 original try + 3 retries)
      connectionTimeout: const Duration(seconds: 2),
    );
    client = Client(config);
  }
}
```

I have tried changing host to localhost, to droplets public address and nothing seems to work. I get this logs

"ClientException with SocketException: Connection refused (OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 111), address = 127.0.0.1, port = 44250, uri=http://127.0.0.1:8108/collections?"

I dont understand why port = 44250. but everytime I try to run it the port changes. Per example here is another log after I run it again:

"ClientException with SocketException: Connection refused (OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 111), address = 127.0.0.1, port = 44408, uri=http://127.0.0.1:8108/collections?"

What am I missing?

In summary:

I can connect with typesense which is installed in my droplet in a docker container whenever I connect with other machines. But once I try to connect inside the droplet (locally) I cannot

Comment: It probably has to do with docker not binding to localhost, try to start your docker with the option `--network="host"`